# is there any way to find or check if the impostor in the nested spaceships no imports

Tags: python

```
  python 
    def test_impostor_flew_away(self):
        spaceship = {
            "cafeteria": {
                "weapons": {
                    "o2": {
                        "communications": {
                            "storage": {
                                "crews": ["super_saiyanXD"]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "crews": ["someotherguy"]
            }
        }

        impostor = "xXimanimpostor9999Xx"
```

this should be output

```
 output = False
```

its nested and i have a hard time doin it
can you all help me

```
    def test_another_impostor(self):
        spaceship = {
            "cafeteria": {
                "storage": {
                    "crews": ["iamnottheimpostor"]
                },
                "crews": [] # this room is empty
            },
            "shields": {
                "crews": ["piwdipi", "davie214", "toasted_guy_45"],
                "weapons": {
                    "crews": ["xXimanimpostor9999Xx"] # impostor is inside this room!
                }
            }
        }



      impostor = "toasted_guy_45"
```

**this should be the output**

```
output = True
```

**how to handle nested dictionary**

> ive look and look for codes and nothing work no imports

Answer (score 1):

Use **recursion** to traverse each nested dictionary :

```
def impostor_is_onboard(spaceship, impostor):
    if isinstance(spaceship, dict):
        return any(impostor_is_onboard(v, impostor) for v in spaceship.values())
    return impostor in spaceship
```

Each time a recursive call is made to `impostor_is_onboard`, we check whether `spaceship` is a dictionary or not.

If it is **not** a dictionary, then it must be a crews list, so we simply return whether the `impostor` string is inside the list, which is the line :

```
return impostor in spaceship
```

However, if it **is** a dictionary, we must look through its values to see if any of those contains the `impostor`. This is handled by the line :

```
return any(impostor_is_onboard(v, impostor) for v in spaceship.values())`
```